# Gradle issues with android support compilation in Unity export

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multidex issue while compiling my project in Unity so I exported the project and imported it to gradle. I've fixed most dependencies but I cannot get rid of the following problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:05:17.012 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:05:17.012 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:05:17.012 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':mainProj:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
12:05:17.012 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/compat/BuildConfig.class
12:05:17.012 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

and that goes to all support* projects. I had similar issues with other sdks but I fixed them by deleting the BuildConfig.class from their classes.jar files. For some reason, when I delete this class for the supportcompat2500 project (in this specific example) it keeps coming back - and I don't know where from.

my settings.gradle is:

```
include ':amazonAppStore'
include ':appLovin'
include ':chartboost'
include ':googleAIDL'
include ':googlePlay'
include ':heyzap'
include ':oneSignalConfig'
include ':samsungApps'
include ':shortcutBadger115'
include ':unityAds'
include ':vungle'
include ':animatedvectordrawable2500'
include ':cardviewv72340'
include ':common'
include ':customtabs2340'
include ':facebookandroidsdk4170'
include ':facebookandroidwrapper790'
include ':onesignalunity'
include ':playservicesads980'
include ':playservicesadslite980'
include ':playservicesbase980'
include ':playservicesclearcut980'
include ':playservicesgass980'
include ':playservicesgcm980'
include ':playservicesiid980'
include ':playserviceslocation980'
include ':playservicestasks980'
include ':supportcompat2500'
include ':supportcoreui2500'
include ':supportcoreutils2500'
include ':supportfragment2500'
include ':supportmediacompat2500'
include ':supportv42500'
include ':supportvectordrawable2500'
include ':mainProj'
```

mainProj.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mainProj.mainProj"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java.com.mainProj.mainProj']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']

            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets.bin.Data']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':amazonAppStore')
    compile project(':appLovin')
    compile project(':chartboost')
    compile project(':googleAIDL')
    compile project(':googlePlay')
    compile project(':cardviewv72340')
    compile project(':customtabs2340')
    compile project(':heyzap')
    compile project(':oneSignalConfig')
    compile project(':samsungApps')
    compile project(':shortcutBadger115')
    compile project(':unityAds')
    compile project(':vungle')
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':facebookandroidsdk4170')
    compile project(':facebookandroidwrapper790')
    compile project(':onesignalunity')
    compile project(':playservicesads980')
    compile project(':playservicesadslite980')
    compile project(':playservicesbase980')
    compile project(':playservicesclearcut980')
    compile project(':playservicesgass980')
    compile project(':playservicesgcm980')
    compile project(':playservicesiid980')
    compile project(':playserviceslocation980')
    compile project(':playservicestasks980')
    compile project(':supportcompat2500')
    compile project(':supportcoreui2500')
    compile project(':supportcoreutils2500')
    compile project(':supportfragment2500')
    compile project(':supportmediacompat2500')
    compile project(':supportv42500')
    compile project(':supportvectordrawable2500')
}
```

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any advice/referenece. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

```
facebookandroidwrapper790
```

already include com.android.support and all of its sub-projects.
I've removed all

```
compile project(':support*')
```